# Unable to insert data into mysql but no error message shown

Tags: php, mysql

Was trying to make a student register page but the data won't insert into database and there was no error message shown so i'm not sure where the problem is. Any help is appreciated!
Here's the code:

```
    <form onsubmit="return Add_Validate()" class="form-horizontal"  action="AddStudent.php" method="POST">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Student</h4>
      </div> 
      <div class="modal-body">


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Student Name </label>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Add_Student_Name" placeholder="Student Name" name="Student_Name1" autocomplete="off" required>
                </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
            <label  class="col-sm-3 control-label">Gender </label>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <select class="form-control" id="Add_Student_Gender" name="Student_Gender1" required>
                    <option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                  </select>
                </div></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address </label>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Add_Student_Address" placeholder="Address" name="Student_Address1" autocomplete="off" required>
                </div>
        </div>          

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contact Number </label>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Add_Contact_Number" placeholder="Contact Number" name="Contact_Number1" autocomplete="off" required>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email </label>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Add_Student_Email" placeholder="Email" name="Student_Email1" autocomplete="off" required>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Faculty </label>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control" name="Add_Faculty1" id="FacultyName" required>
                    <option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>
                    <?php $query_faculty="SELECT FacultyName FROM `faculty`";
                    $result_faculty = mysqli_query($connect, $query_faculty) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
                    while($row_faculty=mysqli_fetch_array($result_faculty)) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_faculty['FacultyName'] ?>"><?php echo $row_faculty['FacultyName'] ?></option>
                <?php } ?></select></div></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label  class="col-sm-3 control-label">Username </label>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Add_Student_Username" placeholder="Username" name="Student_Username1" autocomplete="off" required>
                </div></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password </label>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Add_Password" placeholder="Password" name="Student_Password1" autocomplete="off" required>
                </div>
        </div>
```

And SQL command:

```
<?php require 'php_action/db_connect.php'; 

if($_POST) {    

$Student_Name= $_POST['Student_Name1'];
$Student_Gender= $_POST['Student_Gender1'];
$Student_Address= $_POST['Student_Address1'];
$Contact_Number= $_POST['Contact_Number1'];
$Student_Email= $_POST['Student_Email1'];
$FacultyName= $_POST['Add_Faculty1'];
$Student_Username= $_POST['Student_Username1'];
$Password= $_POST['Student_Password1'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO student (Student_Name,Student_Gender,Student_Address,Contact_Number,Student_Email,FacultyName,Student_Username,Password) VALUES ('$Student_Name', '$Student_Gender','$Student_Address','$Contact_Number','$Student_Email','$FacultyName','$Student_Username','$Password')";



if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<SCRIPT>alert('Student successfully added!');document.location='Student_Register.php'</SCRIPT>";
} 
else {
    echo "<SCRIPT>alert('Student add unsuccessful!');document.location='Student_Register.php'</SCRIPT>";
}


}
$connect->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: You get the "successfully added" alert?

Comment: You should learn to use prepared statements to prevent SQL-injection.

Comment: @Barmar i get the add unsuccessful message but no error message shown

Comment: no error message shown because you are not showing a mysql error message, in your else try to print out `$connect->errorInfo()` in case you are using PDO , or `$connect->error` in case you are using [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) method to check if there was an error with mysql server;

Comment: and as barmar said, your code is vulnerable to sql injection;

Comment: @hassan i tried using `$connect->error` but getting blank page instead

Comment: in your else condition just echo the error, `echo $connect->error;` and check what's going on;

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting an error message because you never get the error message from MySQL and show it in your alert. `$connect->error` will contain the error message, and you can add that to your alert like this:

```
else {
    echo "<SCRIPT>alert('Student add unsuccessful! Reason: ' + " . json_encode($connect->error) . ");document.location='Student_Register.php'</SCRIPT>";
}
```

Comment: `Reason: ' + <?php echo json_encode($connect->error); ?>);document` are you sure ??

Comment: @hassan I think so. `json_encode()` returns a Javascript literal, so you can embed it into the Javascript like that.

Comment: I'm talking about the `<?php` within echo

Comment: it should be something like `... Reason: ' + " . json_encode($connect->error) . "); ....`

Comment: LOL, that's the kind of error I've had to fix in many questions I've answered, I can't believe I made it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, seems to be wrong column name, sorry the all the trouble..... 
Admin please close my question.